# Tibetan Buddhism:Recieving inititation in India/Tibet

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, meditation-recommendation, monasticism, dalai-lama, tantra

I recently read an introductory book on Tibetan Buddhism and intrigued by Tantra & Kalachakra practice. I have been practicing meditation for the last 2-3 years but not under the guidance of a guru. After struggling for 2-3 years I have finally realized the need of a guru so that I can start practicing seriously. Next year, I have 3-month vacation and I'm thinking about going to a monastery in India/Tibet (I live in India) where I can be initiated into tantric practice.

**Which are some of the places in India and Tibet where Tantra/Kalachakra initiation is possible ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should search for vajrayana buddhist temple

> Vajrayana Buddhism is one of the most important and most followed Buddhist tradition in the present states of Buddhism in the whole world. Also known as the Tantric Buddhism, Vajrayana Buddhism is also represented as the Diamond Way or Thunderbolt Way and Indestructible Way. [source](https://www.nepal-tibet-buddhas.com/nepal/vajrayana-buddhism/)

Not sure about India but I think in Nepal you would find a master of Vajrayana. Maybe you can start by taking up a course in Kopan Monastery in Kathmandu. They are not vajrayana of course, they are Gelug branch of Mahayana but when you go there and meet the Monks you  can ask about what you want and they'll guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Going to such a place is good. Until you go you can practice it at your home also. If you can analyze your mind in every moment you are living. And be in consciousness always. And see desires coming to your mind, and destroy the value of it from your mind. Try it. May triple gems bless you.

Answer (score 0):

A book by Anagarika Lama Govinda titled 'The Foundations of Tibetan Mysticism' (pdf) may be useful to build up your knowledge on Tibetan Vajrayana. Lama Govinda, was of German origin and spent many years in Tibet. He was initially in Sri Lanka aligned to the Theravada tradition and subsequently developed an interest in Tibetan Vajrayana. He wrote many books on his spiritual experiences in Tibet. He was a lecturer at the University of Shantiniketan and a world renowned scholar. He had the rare ability to unknot profound spiritual questions and explain them in lucid terms. Many yogis who were interested in the Tibetan tradition were inspired by him. He died in California several decades ago. His writings may inspire you too.